# Notice: Undefined indexes : username, first_name,last_name in...index.php

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm making a small project.
After testing my dbconnection all was alright,than I add some data to the DB and it works, than i want to see some data from table and see this notice.
This is my code

```
***index.php***
require_once("../includes/database.php");
require_once("../includes/users.php");
if(isset ($database)) {echo"true";}else {echo "false";}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$result_set = $database->query($sql);
$found_user = $database->fetch_array($result_set);
echo $found_user['username'];

echo "<hr />";

$found_user = User::find_by_id(1);
echo $found_user['username'];

echo "<hr />";

$user_set = User::find_all();
while ($user = $database->fetch_array($user_set)) {
    echo "User: ". $user['username'] ."<br />";
    echo "Name: ". $user['first_name'] . " " . $user['last_name'] ."<br /><br />";
}
```

My file users.php

```
class User{
    public static function find_all(){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
        return $result_set;
    }

    public static function find_by_id($id=0){
        global $database;
        $result_set = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        $found =$database->fetch_array($result_set);
        return $found;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump()`ing the $user array to see what's inside?

Comment: try printing $user; inside your loop and see what it displays

Comment: Straw, Poria. it displays array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(13) "olegsavchuk12" [2]=> string(4) "1111" [3]=> string(4) "Oleg" [4]=> string(7) "Savchuk" } }

Comment: Error is obvious you don't have any first_name,last_name as indexes instead you have 0,1,2

Comment: var_dump($user); your query probably don't bring back those fields